# LTspice: weird behavior of simple RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, modeling

I try to model a simple RC circuit with input of 2 A DC and I get an out voltage (Vc) of 2 TV. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image]

**EDIT:**
This is for MacOS

Comment: When you run a simulator mark the option “start voltage source from zero”.

Comment: Also, your circuit would make more sense if you used a voltage source instead of a current source.

Comment: Just for completeness here I can explain why you get the result you do.  LTspice's topology checker is detecting that node `Vc` is floating and therefore automatically adds (behind the scenes) a 1 teraohm resistor to ground.  So 2A into 1 teraohm is equal to 2 teravolts.  As explained in the answers, if you don't put an initial condition on the voltage across the capacitor then the simulation will begin with the capacitor fully charged and therefore an open circuit.  So you just have I1, R1, and the "hidden" 1 teraohm resistor.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You need to connect a 5 G Ohm resistor across the capacitor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### note 1 about the .TRAN card

I guess, first off, your **.TRAN** card is providing \$10\:\text{s}\$ as an initial step-size guess (as well as a plotting increment.) This is unusual. But it's fine, too. I'm just being pedantic to note it here.

#### note 2 about the .TRAN card

You are specifying an end-time of \$100\:\text{s}\$ for the run. Again, just being pedantic for now.

#### initial transient solution

Spice simulators will usually first try to find the DC operating point of the circuit. This is called the "initial transient solution" step (sometimes shortened to **ITS**), which takes place immediately prior to \$t=0\$.

There is an option called UIC on the .TRAN card that will tell Spice to avoid this initial **ITS** step.

The use of UIC on the **.TRAN** card means that Spice will not go through the **ITS** step.

Instead, when using this option, the initial value of every single energy storage (voltage/capacitor and current/inductor) device to be treated as zero -- except for those which are explicitly provided using the **.IC** card. (You can add as many **.IC** cards as you feel you need.)

#### your situation, as given

So, without the **UIC** option on the **.TRAN** card, Spice will go through the **ITS** step.

(*In doing so, it will still look for specific **.IC** cards and set things as indicated. But aside from any modifications by **.IC** cards, the other energy storage devices (inductors and capacitors) will be initialized with zero stored energy.*)

This means it will attempt to find a \$t\to\infty\$ solution before starting the run. And in your case, this means finding a ***very large*** result as the starting point of the run.

This isn't what you want.

So check off the **UIC** option of the **.TRAN** card. This will avoid the **ITS** step.

#### results

If you do as I suggested, then you will expect to see \$\frac{\text{d}\,V}{\text{d}t}=\frac{I}{C}=\frac{2\:\text{A}}{20\:\mu\text{F}}=100\:\text{k}\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}}\$. So, in \$t=100\:\text{s}\$ you would expect to see \$10\:\text{MV}\$ at the output.

Let's see:

[image]

Yup! Looks right to me!

Comment: If I recall correctly (been a while since I used it), the Mac version is lacking in a lot of the GUI hand-holding menus that the Windows version has. So I don't think there is a simulation command menu, and therefore no checkboxes to check. The user has to type in the `.tran` command directly, which also explains why they ended up with a strange `.tran` command. Usually it's either 1, 3, or 4 time parameters. Never 2. Anyway, in one of Mike Engelhardt's live talks he boasted about this "new" UI in the Mac version. It seems like this same non-hand holding approach made its way over to QSPICE.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the simulation does a DC operating point, and so it runs the circuit and figures out the starting voltage. Sometimes it can get confused

"Ctrl-RightClick on the capacitor. In the SpiceLine cell, type "IC=0", for example, to set its initial voltage to 0V"

Changed 2V to 0V where applicable

Source: [How to define the initial charge of a capacitor in SPICE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237337/how-to-define-the-initial-charge-of-a-capacitor-in-spice)

Comment: Doesn't work for me on MacOS

Comment: @user510  It should work, so I'm assuming on the Mac version it's a different key-command to get into "super expert mode" to change the `SpiceLine` field.  Alternatively, you can just add the IC=0 right after the capacitance value such that it reads like this: `20u IC=0`.